# UITableView inside UICollectionView -> [error] unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, storyboard

I have a UITableView inside each cell of a UICollectionView.

I referenced the table view to a FeedCell class, which is a class for each cell in the collection view. However, I got an error saying

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

when trying to access the tableView object in the FeedCell class. I triple checked that I referenced the table view from the storyboard correctly, so I'm assuming there's something else that's causing it to be nil, but I'm not sure what it is. Does anyone have a clue about how to fix this?

This is my VC where both the collection view and the table view lies.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        collectionView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FeedCell")
    }

    // for feedcell and its collection view
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        cell.backgroundColor = backgrounds[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let collectionViewCell = cell as? FeedCell else { return }

        collectionViewCell.setTableViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }

    // conform to tableview protocol for hometable
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images[tableView.tag].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.imageView?.image = images[tableView.tag][indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }


}
```

And here's a cell of the collection view where I reference the table view.

```
class FeedCell: BaseCollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

}


extension FeedCell {

    func setTableViewDataSourceDelegate
        <D: UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate>
        (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

        # ERROR!
        tableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        tableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        tableView.tag = row
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: What line is your error on?

Comment: It's line "tableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate". I included a comment before the line with the error.

Comment: Just remove that lines tableView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        tableView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate and put delegates from storyboard and its work fine

Comment: I tried that, but I cannot put the delegate and the data source to FeedCell because it's a subclass of collection view cells. I could point the delegate and the data source only to the collection view from Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
 (dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int)
```

You cast it as the variable: D

Use this instead:

```
tableView.dataSource = D
tableView.delegate = D
```

Comment: The erros is `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value f` for the tableView object. So with your solution, the tableView object still remains nil